# How to convert List <JSONObject> to Json String in java (com.amazonaws.util.json.JSONObject)

Tags: java, json, objectmapper

com.amazonaws.util.json.JSONObject
Below is the List, i want to convert it into json string.

`List<JSONObject> jsonObjlist` is

```
[{"Attribute":"EmailAddress","Value":"abc@yahoo.com"}, {"Attribute":"Source","Value":"Missing_Fixed"}, {"Attribute":"mx_Lead_Status","Value":"Registered User"}, {"Attribute":"mx_Age","Value":""}, {"Attribute":"mx_LoginID","Value":"abc@yahoo.com"}, {"Attribute":"mx_Registration_Source","Value":"EMAIL"}]
```

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
        objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        String arrayToJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(jsonObjlist);
```

Output i get is

```
[{"map":{"Attribute":"EmailAddress","Value":"abc@yahoo.com"}},{"map":{"Attribute":"Source","Value":"Missing_Fixed"}},{"map":{"Attribute":"mx_Lead_Status","Value":"Registered User"}},{"map":{"Attribute":"mx_Age","Value":""}},{"map":{"Attribute":"mx_LoginID","Value":"abc@yahoo.com"}},{"map":{"Attribute":"mx_Registration_Source","Value":"EMAIL"}}]
```

Desired out put is

```
"[{"Attribute":"EmailAddress","Value":"abc@yahoo.com"}, {"Attribute":"Source","Value":"Missing_Fixed"}, {"Attribute":"mx_Lead_Status","Value":"Registered User"}, {"Attribute":"mx_Age","Value":""}, {"Attribute":"mx_LoginID","Value":"abc@yahoo.com"}, {"Attribute":"mx_Registration_Source","Value":"EMAIL"}]"
```

Comment: You should also add your desired output, not just the one you get now.

Comment: If you are using Amazon AWS's JSONObject, you should also include relevant `import` statements, as most readers (including me) will otherwise assume that you are using `org.json` classes.

Comment: Yes using com.amazonaws.util.json.JSONObject

Answer (score 6):

You should convert your list to a JSON Array, and just use its `toString()` function:

```
JSONArray myArray = new JSONArray(jsonObjlist);

// ...
String arrayToJson = myArray.toString(2);
```

The int parameter specifies the indent factor to use for formatting.

Comment: I am getting this
{"myArrayList":[{"map":{"Attribute":"EmailAddress","Value":"vinay10949@yahoo.com"}},{"map":{"Attribute":"Source","Value":"Missing_Fixed"}},{"map":{"Attribute":"mx_Lead_Status","Value":"Registered User"}},{"map":{"Attribute":"mx_Age","Value":""}},{"map":{"Attribute":"mx_LoginID","Value":"abc@yahoo.com"}},{"map":{"Attribute":"mx_Registration_Source","Value":"EMAIL"}}]}

Comment: @VinaySawant Right, ObjectMapper is for Java -> JSON objects. You can just use `toString()`, changed my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can also direct use

```
 String jsonString = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(jsonObjectList)
```

To get the desired ouptput

Here is the small example

```
List<JSONObject> jsons = new ArrayList<>();
jsons.add(new JSONObject(ImmutableMap.of("Attribute", "EmailAddress", "Value", "abc@yahoo.com")));
jsons.add(new JSONObject(ImmutableMap.of("Attribute1", "EmailAddress3", "Value1", "abc@yahoo.com1")));
System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(jsons));
```

The output is

```
[{"Value":"abc@yahoo.com","Attribute":"EmailAddress"},{"Attribute1":"EmailAddress3","Value1":"abc@yahoo.com1"}]
```

I suspect there are some toString() method in any object that you have override?

Comment: Isn't this (almost) exactly what the OP tries, and what does not have desired effect?

Comment: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class com.amazonaws.util.json.JSONObject and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0])

Comment: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class com.amazonaws.util.json.JSONObject and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0])

Comment: Did you check if there are any toString method in your bean?

Comment: Just try out what you have tried in the question, but only this time without the toString method. I assume I did not use any kind of bean that's why I cannot reproduce it.